# V-tooltip: Close Popover from a method

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

In VueJS, I'm using v-tooltip (https://github.com/Akryum/v-tooltip) for popovers.

In order to close a popup, they provide a directive called `'v-close-popover'` which I can assign to a button/link inside the popover to close the popup. This works well.

However, I have a requirement where I need to close this popup from a Vue method. But I dn't know how to trigger closing of the popover from the method.

Comment: Maybe you can use the `open` prop to manually control the popover's visibility?

Comment: Did you get some solution for this? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can achieve this.It will display tooltip on mouseOver event and remove on mouseLeave event.
In template->

```
  <i
      id="requiredIcon"
      aria-hidden="true"
      v-tooltip="{content: 'Required option is not available for this question.', show: isOpen, trigger: 'manual'}"
      @mouseover="showTooltip"
      @mouseleave="removeTooltip"
    ></i>
```

In Script->

```
   data() {
        return {
          isOpen: false,
        };
      },
methods:{
    showTooltip() {
            this.isOpen = true;
        },
     removeTooltip() {
          this.isOpen = false;
        }
}
```

Comment: This solution can work if you have only one popover on page, but there can be multiple.

Comment: @ImranFarooq you will have to use a unique variable for particular tool tip. You can update isOpen variable accordingly (Maybe an array/object for all of your tool tips).

Comment: actually there are multiple tooltips with each record and there are thousands of records, so this is not manageable to have a unique variable for each tooltip.

Comment: @ImranFarooq Are you giving a unique id to each tooltip ? (id="requiredIcon") Then you can easily achieve this by passing your id to function and using that id name with show parameter

Comment: Ideally there should be a way to close all tooltips with one command, id or not.

Answer (score 0):

In case anybody else stumbles upon this issue, the v-popover component has a `hide` method. So if you were to place a ref on your popover component then you can access the hide method from it and call it :)

Answer (score 0):

The docs don't do a good job surfacing this, the `#popper` in the template [has a slot component for `hide`](https://floating-vue.starpad.dev/guide/component#hide-from-slot), which you can then pass to the vue method that you want to call. for example:

```js
<VDropdown>
  <button>Click me</button>

  <template #popper="{ hide }">
    <form @submit.prevent="handleSubmit(hide)>
      <!-- ... -->
    </form>
  </template>
</VDropdown>
```

now your vue method would need to get updated:

```
const handleSubmit(hide: () => void) => {
  // => submit logic
  hide()
}
```